# how to fix imports and format for java using tool like goimports?

Tags: java

Is there some tool like `goimports` for java? so that we could fix the codes quickly not depending on IDE.

I try this tool, but it only formats the codes, and does not work for entire dir recursively:

https://github.com/google/google-java-format

Comment: Why *not depending on IDE*, every developer use an IDE?

Comment: Fixing imports should never be a batch operation. Every developer should ensure that imports are correct, *before* checking in code, and it is easy to do with an IDE. If you rely on batch processing, you need to re-think your practices, because they are wrong. Fix the cause, not the symptom!

Comment: I was about to answer your question about package management/deployment, which you unfortunately deleted. Anyway, you're asking the right questions.;-)

Comment: In Eclipse, you have _Source > Organize Imports_ (Ctrl+Shift+0) which adds missing import statements and removes unused import statements but does not add required JARs to the Java build path. In the future, such a feature could be provided by a language server via LSP (as part of the Java Development Kit) instead be implemented by each IDE.

Comment: It might be fine to require all imports to be correct for a push, but I do a lot of "experimental" coding where I have code that I insert and/or comment out and run google-java-import on every file save, but it deletes unused imports (e.g. for code I have commented out), so when I push the build button, I have to wade through errors fixing up the imports that were there but google-java-format has deleted when I uncomment the code.

Comment: As to why not an IDE, I don't know an IDE that lets me write  lisp macros to modify code.  When you show me an IDE that does all Emacs can do and let's me customize it with my own lisp, I will switch.

Comment: By the way, when I was at Google, they had just such a tool that added imports for you, called JADE or something like it.  I don't mind having the imports be correct.  I just don't want to spend 10 minutes fixing them up after I comment out a bunch of code that is *temporarily* irrelevant and put it back after I have worked on what I didn't want that code interfering with.